# .htaccess allows images only

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I know similar questions have been asked, but none of it guided me to the right solution.

**What I want to do**

Use .htaccess in a /uploads folder to ensure that only file with appropriate extension can be uploaded. (e.g. jpg, png)

**What I have done**

- modify /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
  to allow overwrite of .htaccess file
- create .htaccess file in /uploads folder

To test if .htaccess has been read, I have tried to put garbage in .htaccess file and access it from the browser. Corresponding error has been generated, therefore, .htaccess file is working properly.

**Problem**

The following script has been added to .htaccess
         
         order deny,allow
         deny from all

However, I am still able to upload files with any extensions to /uploads folder.

I have tried different suggestions from similar posts with no luck. Looking for new directions from you guys.

Thanks.

Comment: i do not think, what you are trying to achieve is possible using .htaccess, why not limit the upload to only images in the script that is actually uploading the files!?

Comment: You can have your server only serve files in that directory ending in specific extensions. Your PHP should be modified though to disallow unapproved extensions. Also extensions can be manipulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a GET method with base64 encoded string in your url, you can use .htaccess to redirect to an upload script base on the mime-type of that string. however I guess this is not what you trynna achieve. .htaccess is not appropriate in your case. if you need to control the extension of an uploaded file, you should make the process directly in your uploading script (php, python, whatever).

Comment: I will do it through my php uploading script....I just wonder then in what cases or situations ".htaccess" should be used to restrict file type in a directory? thanks.

Comment: The file type doesn't guarantee it's contents, someone cam simply rename virus.exe into my_photo.jpg and this will pass the file type check. On the other way around, I might have downloaded an nice jpeg image, however the server sent it without extension. As @발렌텐 suggested, the best approach would be to validate the contents not the file type. And for images that's pretty simple, just call getimagesize().

Comment: very practical answer, will add it as part of the validation rules, thanks Cristik

Answer (score 2):

The name of the uploaded file is part of the body of the POST request the browser is making to the server, thus the .htaccess rules can't be enforced in your situation. Unless you are using some uploading schema, like creating a placeholder on the server and then submitting the file to that placeholder.

Comment: file name is just part of the post request <--- nice explanation!